# IntelliJ Idea integration with trac

Tags: intellij-idea, trac, jetbrains-ide

I'm using Intellij Idea 14.1.4 on a Windows 10. I'm having trouble getting the Trac (Task Management) integration plugin to work.

Idea able connect to Trac ( 0.12.3 ) server and download a list of task for user, but it didn't show description of task and items "Show" and "Open" in Tools > Task & Contexts menu are disabled.

Any suggestion?

Task server in IntelliJ params:

- Server URL:  http://tsscourse.repositoryhosting.com/trac/tsscourse_test/login/rpc
- user: test_user
- Password: 1111

Trac user rights:

- BROWSER_VIEW
- CHANGESET_VIEW
- EMAIL_VIEW
- FILE_VIEW
- LOG_VIEW
- MILESTONE_VIEW
- REPORT_VIEW
- ROADMAP_VIEW
- SEARCH_VIEW
- TICKET_ADMIN
- TICKET_APPEND
- TICKET_CHGPROP
- TICKET_EDIT_CC
- TICKET_EDIT_COMMENT
- TICKET_EDIT_DESCRIPTION
- TICKET_MODIFY
- TICKET_VIEW
- TIMELINE_VIEW
- WIKI_VIEW
- XML_RPC

Comment: I see the same behavior with PyCharm and I've never understood whether this is a limitation of working with Trac from PyCharm or if I'm doing something wrong. There doesn't seem to be much documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH! it is a all JetBrains issue. I have found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94354